# Bootstrap menu CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, hover, navbar

I have made an site with bootstrap, but somehow i can't make the menu do as i want.

[My site with the problem](http://www.multisupport.dk)

If you click lets say 'Ydelser' and then scroll back to the top, Both 'Ydelser' and 'Home' are now white, i would like at that point only home was white.

Example, if lets say you click on 'the brand / the logo' and then scroll down, the 'Home' stays white, until you reach the point of the site, where it goes from 'home' to 'ydelser' then 'ydelser' turns white background

So literally, i would like the links to have a white background when theyre active, and when they stop being active, the background should be as the others again.

** Note **

If i click 'ydelser' and scroll to the top, the white background can be removed by clicking anywhere randomly on the site - if that can help somehow to solve the issue.

**What have i tried**

I have basicly tried everything that i know off, tried to change most a:active, a:hover css codes, and nothing seems to work.

Comment: Updated my answer for the active element as well, it seemed to still use the background color with separate :focus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs because you have the same code on `:focus` for those li items

```
.navbar-default .nav>li.active>a:focus {
    //code for css is here
}
```

on *line 44* in *Multisupport.css*.
This forces the same css style after you click the buttons. Remove that focus and it should be fine.

Comment: I have now changed to transparent background, didn't fix it, and now i totally removed the css from multisupport.css, and the site still acts the same weird way

And thanks for the already supplied help

Comment: I solved the problem, what i had to to, was to remove the white background of the already made :focus code :) 

Florin, i gave you Question answered mark, since your solution helped me, just in another css than Multisupport :) , thanks for the great help, apreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** Updated the CSS to include the `.active a:focus` element as well

It seems that your problem is in the **:focus** that you must adjust via CSS.

Do the following:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
   background-color: transparent; /* You can also try !important if it just keeps including the background color in there */
}
```

And some additional styling attributes if you so wish.

Comment: He can better remove the already existing code, instead of rewriting another style...

Comment: That depends if he has downloaded the Bootstrap CSS or just got it by CDN. This solution is making no assumptions of it and solves the problem for both those who have it locally and who have used CDN instead.

Comment: That's true. You made your point. I was just checking his website with inspect element and I saw lot's of :focus code there and for some reasons I assumed he has written that code and that he should remove it :)